# failed to deploy Travis CI `Python`

Tags: python-3.x, travis-ci

I got the below error when tried to run the build in `travis`. I'm new to travis and following some websites to create the builds for `Python` project.

```
The command "coverage run -m pytest test.py" exited with 0.
3.23s$ coverage html -d docs/report/coverage/
The command "coverage html -d docs/report/coverage/" exited with 0.
after_success
0.17s$ coveralls
dpl_0
1.25s$ rvm $(travis_internal_ruby) --fuzzy do ruby -S gem install dpl
invalid option "--token="
failed to deploy
```

Any insights will be helpful and i saw `secure` keyword in `.travis.yml` page and may i know what is it and it's use. How to generate the `secure` key in windows?

Comment: I assume you tried to google `travis invalid option "--token="` ?

Comment: i tried but nothing seems helpful.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i found the solution for my problem.

I forgot to mention `secure` in `.travis.yml` file.

`env:
  global:
    secure: hash value`
`

I think we can directly mention the token value directly in travis repository page instead of yml file.